# How to add isset to $_GET without breaking code

Tags: php, get, isset

I am using php app written by other developer, however when errors are on, PHP reports Undefined Index (and lots of them)

usuall code looks like this:

```
if ( $_GET["logout"] ){ unset($_SESSION); session_destroy(); }
if ( !$_SESSION['cp_auth'][ $config["private_hash"] ] ){ header("Location: " . $config["urlPath"] . "/" . $config["folder_admin"] . "/login.php"); }
```

I am trying to add isset like so:

```
if ( isset($_GET["logout"]) ){ unset($_SESSION); session_destroy(); }
```

but I am doing if obviously wrong because I end up in redirect loop once I close the session and trying to reach login page.

How would I add isset correctly so it won't display errors AND work?

Thanks

Comment: You need to check if the index exists before using it. `if ( !empty($_GET["logout"]) ){ session_destroy(); }`. So look for `empty()` or `isset()`.

Comment: We can't tell because from this code if you are redir to login and login, theoretically it should set `$_SESSION['cp_auth'][ $config["private_hash"]` and so no redir loop.